# maching convolution filters to results

Tags: filters, convolution, filtering

I am practicing for an exam and I need help in the following question (it is just for me- no grade...)

we get an input image, 6 convolution filters and 6 results.
we need to find the matches between the filters to the result images.

[image: the question is here]

so far I found that filter 3 matches to image D and filter 4 matches to image f.

now I stuck and I would appreciate any help.
thanks!

**EDIT:** the origin of all the filters is in the center.

Comment: Do you recognize the filters? Have you looked at their frequency response? What would the filter for autocorrelation look like?

Comment: I don't know what is autocorrelation filter.. I know that filter 1 is the sum of 2 pixels from the neighborhood, filter 2 is prewitt, filter 3 is kind of average and filter 4 is gaussian. I don't know what are the other two filters...

Comment: You know Prewitt is used for edge detection, so what would you expect that result to look like? Gaussians blur, right? Filter 3 is not just a "kind of average". Plot its frequency response and you'll see a kind of high-pass filter. Filter 6 is a 2-D sinc. What's the frequency response of a 2-D sinc? It's a low-pass filter. Filter 5 is a reversed copy of the input image? What do you get when you convolve an image with a reversed copy of itself? The autocorrelation. What would you expect the autocorrelation to look like?

Comment: Lastly, filter 1 will essentially the sum of two offset versions of the input image. I'd expect it to look blurry but in a non-smooth manner.

Comment: First of all , thanks!
I just want to be sure:
Filter 3 is high pass filter so it creates image A,
Filter 6 is 2D sinc function so it creates image D (we can see circles in the background),
Filter 4 is Gaussian filter so it creates image F (probably…),
Filter 1 is sum of two pixels so it creates image E (blurry but in a non-smooth manner)

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Now, the last 2 filters:
Filter 2 is prewitt so it finds edges and probably creates  image C but as I know it finds only horizontal edges (because of the x-derivative) and in image C there are many other edges. Am I wrong? 
About filter 6, I really do not know what autocorrelation is. Can you explain it in simple words? If it is complicated I will read about it by myself. 
Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have access to matlab/octave? If so, you can just implement these filters first hand and see what they do.

Comment: Paste this in to matlab for a first example: `x = rgb2gray( imread( 'peppers.png' ) ); imagesc( conv2( double(x), [1 1 1; 0 0 0; -1 -1 -1] ) );'. You'll see that Image A is the output of the prewitt filter.

Comment: So prewitt's output is A and the output of filter 3 is C (it is a sharpening filter). am I right? It is make sense

Comment: I believe that's correct. (I was wrong to call it a high-pass filter. It actually leaves the lower frequencies alone and amplifies the higher ones.)